# Insufficient memory message in error

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a brand new 32GB SD card barely used, my phone even shows that it has 31.23GB of storage available, however when attempting to download an app it says I do not have enough memory. I have double checked that the SD card is the default storage on my device, but to no avail. Please help, I just got the memory card and can't even use it.

Comment: Your phone name? Your Android version? Also, give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said apps installation.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Your SD card has little to do with this error. Please check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some first aid, then [edit] your question with the details Firelord asked for, and with what you've tried and how that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play downloads app data to internal storage first then installs the app to external, hence the low storage message. There is no way to change this without rooting and using a symbolic link.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have apps on an external SD card without you phone being rooted.

Comment: All of them you can't have apps on SD card without root access

Comment: You can not run an app from an external SD card on any android version. His question was why can't I download an appointment when I have space on my external SD card.

Comment: So you figured this doesn't answer the question at all? Apart from which, it's not even true but very much depends on the device and Android version used.